# Search: Simple Form

Tags: simple-search

I'm not sure what is happening. I have used the Simple Search successfully before but am not having any luck with it and EE 2.8.1. Hopefully someone can assist me with this as I'm sure I'm missing something simple :)

Snippet containing the simple search tag:

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="blog" result_page="blog/search" search_in="everywhere" status="open" where="all" show_expired="yes" show_future_entries="yes"}
<input type="text" id="keywords" name="keywords" placeholder="Enter your search" class="pull-left">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Here's my `/blog/search` template which was taken directly from the documentation:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>{lang:title}</th>
        <th>{lang:excerpt}</th>
        <th>{lang:author}</th>
        <th>{lang:date}</th>
        <th>{lang:total_comments}</th>
        <th>{lang:recent_comments}</th>
    </tr>

{exp:search:search_results switch="resultRowOne|resultRowTwo"}

    <tr class="{switch}">
        <td width="30%" valign="top"><b><a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a></b></td>
        <td width="30%" valign="top">{excerpt}</td>
        <td width="10%" valign="top"><a href="{member_path='member/index'}">{author}</a></td>
        <td width="10%" valign="top">{entry_date format="%m/%d/%y"}</td>
        <td width="10%" valign="top">{comment_total}</td>
        <td width="10%" valign="top">{recent_comment_date format="%m/%d/%y"}</td>
    </tr>

    {if count == total_results}
        </table>
    {/if}

    {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}

{/exp:search:search_results}

</table>
```

I'm attempting to search within a GRID field and have my Field Marked as Searchable as well as the column I want to search in. I have several Blog Entries setup with various content. Most of them have the word "Testing" in them yet when I search for that word I get no results.

What else could I be missing?

### #

What's also weird is that sometimes the "Error" page (which pulls in the User Message Template) has the Heading missing at times like so. I doubt it's related but still strange!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a no results page?

Comment: I have, but that doesn't seem to matter either.

Comment: Is the content "testing" in one of the searchable fields in an entry in the `blog` channel with a status of `open`?

Comment: Yes the page in question is here: http://placewise.uldev.co/blog I can't search titles or Grid Fields although the grid field type and each comment is set to searchable.

Comment: Was this grid field always searchable, or did you change that setting later? If later, you might be affected by [this bug](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19901/why-is-simple-search-not-getting-results-from-the-grid-field-in-2.7.2). (re-saving the entry should make it show up)

Comment: I believe it always was on, but I'll look at that bug. Low Search isn't working either but it's possible that's not setup correctly, but still giving me the same problem. So it MUST be a bug right?  :)

Comment: I'm using 2.9 so would that 2.7.2 bug still be a problem?

Comment: I created a new entry in the Blog Channel and nothing was searchable and also resaved all of the other entries and still not searchable.

Comment: For giggles I setup a text input field and set it to searchable and no results came back for that either :///

Comment: Should I report this as a bug? I can't see what else it would be.

Comment: So no response on this? I haven't heard anything about my bug report too: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20520 Shouldn't have used this version :(

Comment: I'd be happy to take a look and troubleshoot directly for you if you want to put in a ticket with your log in info.

Comment: Thanks DJ. KC is helping me directly as I just sent him my repo credentials. Hopefully we can squash this and the login issues I am having :) Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this was a FREEBIE issue. I set "search" to always parse and POOF! Thanks to Kevin @ Ellis Lab for the help on this one!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing search_in="everywhere" with search_in="entries" in the exp:search:simple_form tag. I remember having problems with this with EE 2.8.1. Also try removing  where="all".

I hope this helps

Comment: None of that helped :(

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with our search form and it ended up being we had stickies turned off in our server, so our session was pointing to another server when we hit submit. Thus shooting this type of error because it was looking for something that didn't exist in that server. -- I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to be more clear about this part... "we had stickies turned off in our server"?

Comment: sure Anna, say you have 2 backend servers, www1.example.com and www2.example.com. You’d add the following to your backend vhost configuation :

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* – [CO=BALANCEID:balancer.www1:.example.com][/code]then do the same for www2, obviously changing the cookie val to reflect this. You then need to tell your frontend proxy that it should look for this cookie, and which server each "route" refers to :

Comment: ProxyPass / balancer://cluster/ lbmethod=byrequests stickysession=BALANCEID
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://cluster/
<Proxy balancer://cluster>
  BalancerMember http://www1.example.com route=www1
  BalancerMember http://www2.example.com route=www2
</Proxy>

Comment: @javi please update your answer, rather than adding comments.